# Bootstrap Navbar with button active - I cannot clear it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have this older site (Bootstrap 3.3.6) I put together for a client and have noticed that a button in the navbar is noted as active and I can't seem to clear it.

It visually looks like this :

[Screenshot of issue with buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17kx5.png)

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#registration">REGISTRATION &amp; PROGRAMS</a>
                </li>                                    
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#coaches">OUR COACHES</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
                </li>                   
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/225011327510460/?fref=nf"><img src="img/FB-f-Logo50px.png" alt="Find us on Facebook!"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

When I view it under active circumstances the button for CONTACT displays as such :

```
<li class="active">
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
                </li>
```

CSS :

```
a   {
font-family: "HypatiaSansPro-Regular";
color:#CC3333;}

.btn    {
background-color: #CC3333;
outline-color: #CC3333;}

.btn:hover,
.btn:focus,
.btn.active {
background-color: #993333;
outline-color: #CC3333;} 

.contact-section {
padding-top: 100px;
padding-top: 100px;
padding-bottom: 50px;
text-align: center;
background: #eee;}
```

If I change the order of the buttons I will get the same issue for any of the buttons that are last.

This is a one page bootstrap site, the page has 3 anchors. I can send private messages of the site in question if it helps.

It's a minor issue, but it is really bothering me that there is a conflict and I cannot clear it. Any feedback?

Comment: there must be some code that is adding active class to it somewhere.

Comment: You're correct, I cannot find that conflict.... [this is the site](http://www.watfordskatingclub.com/) if you want to take a look at it... I cannot figure it out and it's driving me a bit mad.

Comment: Also, the HTML code block and CSS classes don't seem to match as well. I can't see any use of class `.btn`

Comment: From looking at the page, my guess is that it's an issue with scrollspy since none of your Javascript even references `.active`. This is assuming you don't have a backend that would be adding this class for some reason.

Comment: Thanks Chase, I'm getting the same felling... It's a very simple site, and I didn't alter any of the native Bootstrap CSS or backend files. I think my issue comes from the scrollspy thinking it's natively in the contact section.... for the life of me I can't get it to turn off.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap adds a class that highlights the active element:

```
.navbar-nav>.active>a{
  color: #555;
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
}
```

You can overwrite that selector by placing the same selector with the values you want in a css stylesheet loaded after bootstrap's css.

```
.navbar-nav>.active>a{
  color: #777;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Alternatively you can to remove the `.active` class somehow. But I think bootstrap adds that automatically. So that would probably be a hassle to do.

Comment: Thanks RMo , it did not work on this end. I think I have a bigger conflict with my scrollspy and on of my anchor sections. I appreciate you having a look-see!